# jQuery POST to localhost returns HTTP 501 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, netcat

I am trying to make a jQuery POST request from a locally hosted web-page to a locally hosted server.

My server listens at 
When I send a POST request using my [HTTP client](https://luckymarmot.com/paw), I receive a `201 created` response, as I expect.

Now, I try to send the same request using jQuery:

```
function postAppointment() {

    $.post({
        url:'http://localhost:8085/appointments',
        data: appointmentFactory(),
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'

        }
    });
}
```

I receive the following error message from the Safari error console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented) ([object Object], line 0)
```

However, I'm not so sure the server is actually responding, because I have tried sending the requests to `netcat` and it is not printing out any requests, while if I use my GUI HTTP client, `netcat` does print out the requests.

So... to me this seems to be a client-side issue, since my backend-service is confirmed to be working by my GUI HTTP client. I thought maybe this problem has to do with how I am serving my page, so I have tried serving the page:

1. Opening directly from the Finder
2. Opening via IDE link which seems to run a server (JetBrains WebStorm)
3. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Is there a client-side configuration I am missing which is preventing me from sending a request?

Thanks for any help.

And in case you are wondering, `appointmentFactory()` returns

```
Object
eventName: "Fiesta Forever"
phoneNumber: "13125555555"
time: Thu Dec 18 2014 17:15:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
__proto__: Object
```

And I have also sent the request by parsing the object with `JSON.stringify()`.... I'm not sure if that is done automatically.

I also tried the request via Desktop Chrome, and received the following additional information:
[image]

Thanks again for any help.

-Blake

Comment: Might be duplicate of this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121451/why-do-i-get-this-501-not-implemented-error

Comment: `data` cannot simply be a JavaScript object otherwise jQuery will encode it using URL encoding (`name=value&...`) -- it doesn't check the content type. You need to serialize it into a JSON string manually.

Comment: Thanks Cameron, I will send future requests using JSON.stringify()... I wasn't sure if this was done automatically.

Comment: Regarding JSONP, are the client and server considered to be on a different domain if they are both running on localhost?